# How to filter data on last successful trigger run in ADF(Azure Data Factory) V2 in copy activity ( NoSQL to SQL )?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF pipenine having only copy activity from Cosmos Mongo DB and copying to SQL Server.
Currently I am truncating the table every time the pipeline is run then copy all the data.
But now I want to add a filtering on one field say(lastModifiedTime) and comparing with the last successful trigger run.

Can anyone suggest me the expression which can be used here to put as a filter in the source for incremental updates?

I totally want to avoid truncating tables in the precopy script.

Comment: Hi,if my answer helps you,would you please accept it to end it?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Incrementally copy data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) in ADF, MongoDB connector is not supported so far. My workaround is adding a outside static variable to store every end time of pipeline.

***Step1-*** Add an Azure function activity after the copy activity. If the copy activity executes successfully, pass the end of execution time into azure function as parameters. Such as `utcnow()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions

***Step2-*** Inside Azure function method, store the `time` into some place which could be accessed later, such as Blob Storage.

***Step3-*** Next trigger run,get the last execute time with [Look Up activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) from blob storage before the copy activity and set it into [set variable activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) so that you could use it in the next step.

***Step4-*** Add [filter condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb#copy-activity-properties) in the MongoDB source dataset with the value of set variable activity.